# How to create a partially filled column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a `df_trg` with, say 10 rows numbered `0-9`.

I get from various sources values for an additional column `foo` which contains only a **subset** of rows, e.g. `S1` has `0-3, 7, 9` and `S2` has `4, 6`.

I would like to get a data frame with a single new column `foo` where some rows may remain `NaN`.

> Is there a "nicer" way other than:

```
df_trg['foo'] = np.nan
for src in sources:
    df_trg['foo'][df_trg.index.isin(src.index)] = src
```

> for example, using `join` or `merge`?

Comment: try: `df_trg.merge(S1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')`

Comment: But thats me guessing since you didn't provide any example dataset.

Comment: @Erfan I tried that, but it doesn't work for multiple `Sx`. It adds multiple columns if I wrap that line in a `reduce`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create the source DataFrame (*df*), *s1* and *s2* (*Series* objects with
updating data) and a list of them (*sources*):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 51).reshape((5, -1)).T)
s1 = pd.Series([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9])
s2 = pd.Series([27, 28], index=[4, 6])
sources = [s1, s2]
```

Start the computation from adding *foo* column, initially filled with
an empty string:

```
df = df.assign(foo='')
```

Then run the following "updating" loop:

```
for src in sources:
    df.foo.update(other=src)
```

The result is:

```
    0   1   2   3   4 foo
0   1  11  21  31  41  11
1   2  12  22  32  42  12
2   3  13  23  33  43  13
3   4  14  24  34  44  14
4   5  15  25  35  45  27
5   6  16  26  36  46    
6   7  17  27  37  47  28
7   8  18  28  38  48  15
8   9  19  29  39  49    
9  10  20  30  40  50  16
```

In my opinion, this solution is (at least a little) nicer than yours and
shorter.

Alternative: Fill *foo* column initially with *NaN*, but this time
updating values will be converted to *float* (side effect of using *NaN*).

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo. This indeed is a more readable solution - I'll use it.